# how to prioritize html content coming from joomla modules

Tags: joomla, google-pagespeed

Google suggests me to prioritize visible content of my site.

But my website is built in joomla and page content is coming from different joomla modules. is it possible to prioritize dynamic html content.

How can i prioritize my joomla page content..??

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

See this topic on joomla forum:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=827608